# Seeing bs ad URLs on SO... is this a bug?

Tags: bug, advertising

For me at least, some ads are not rendering and a URL is shown instead:

[image: bs ad]

Is anyone else experiencing this bug?

Here is one URL where I see this bug:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826099/how-to-stop-client-error-with-redux-saga`

Here is the ad URL I am seeing instead of an ad:

`https://bs.serving-sys.com/Serving/adServer.bs?c=28&cn=display&pli=1074961873&w=728&h=90&ord=1775446033&ifrm=-1&z=0`

Comment: That particular domain is associated with system-installed malware. You might want to check your computer.

Comment: Will do... many thanks @animuson!